# Real life nonsmooth convex optimization problem

Tags: soft-question, convex-optimization, non-smooth-optimization

I need to find a real world nonsmooth convex optimization problem, and determine the optimality conditions. What would be a basic problem that you would come across in the field, where I could construct it into a convex optimization problem? I am a beginner in studying convex optimization, and so I am not looking for anything too complicated. I only want to utilize the skills that I have learned so far.

Comment: Ok so convex means it has only one global max/min? What does non smooth mean? Isnt differentiable? Sorry I dont know these things but maybe I can still think of a use?

Comment: What about loan repayment finding optimum payment strategy where there are several principles with different interest rates. I think this would have breaks in it yet remaining convex?

Comment: Nonsmooth would mean not differentiable. We have come across that problem. I was looking for other kinds of examples.

Comment: Thanks, I see so that one doesn't fit or you just cant use it?

Answer (score 0):

The [textbook by Boyd and Vandenberghe on convex optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) contains numerous examples.

Comment: I found that book, yet I couldn't see any examples of nonsmooth, not differentiable, problems. I was thinking of just making them nonsmooth. But I was hoping for suggestions of problems that are nonsmooth in nature.

Comment: Any problem in the book that involves the minimization of $\| x \|_{1}$ or $\| x \|_{\infty}$ is non-smooth.  Are you sure you understand what "non-smooth" means?